# Unable to successfully make the second call using the first call response as parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am a beginner in Python and I am trying to access the following data using python.

1) https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corporateHome.html, click on 'Corporate Announcements' under 'Corporate Information' on the left pane.
2) Entering the company symbol (KSCL for example) and selecting the announcement period 
3) Click on any individual row subject to get additional detail

The first two steps translates to the below url 'https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/getAnnouncements.jsp?period=More%20than%203%20Months&symbol=kscl&industry=&subject='. This is working fine in my python requests code.

However I am not able to replicate the third step, the request is successful but I am not getting the data. Following is the code that I am using, I am stuck please help.

I compared all the request headers that are going when I tried this from browser to what I am sending with python and they match. I tried sending cookie too but that didn't work. I think cookie might not be required as the website works in browser after disabling cookies too. I am running this on Python 3.5.

```
import requests as rq
from requests.utils import requote_uri
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import demjson as dj
from urllib.parse import quote

class BuyBack:

  def start(self):

    # Define headers used across all requests
    self.req_headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36',}
    self.req_headers['Accept'] = '*/*'
    self.req_headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br'
    self.getAllSymbols()

  def readAnnouncement(self, pyAnnouncement):
    # This is done using request_html
    symbol = pyAnnouncement['sym']
    desc = pyAnnouncement['desc']
    tstamp = pyAnnouncement['date']
    seqId = pyAnnouncement['seqId']


    payload = {'symbol' : symbol,'desc' : desc, 'tstamp' : tstamp, 'seqId' : seqId}

    quote_payload = {}

    params_string = '?'

    #formats as required with '%20' for spaces
    for(k,v) in payload.items():
      quote_payload [quote(k)] = quote(v)
      params_string += quote(k)
      params_string += '='
      params_string += quote(v)
      params_string += '&'

    params_string = params_string[:-1]
    announDetail_Url = 'https://nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/AnnouncementDetail.jsp'
    self.req_headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/Announcements.html'
    self.req_headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
    self.req_headers['Host'] = 'www.nseindia.com'

    annReqUrl = announDetail_Url + params_string
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get(annReqUrl, headers = self.req_headers)
    print(r.url)
    #I am not getting the proper data in the response 
    print(r.content)
    print(r.request.headers)

  def getAllSymbols(self):
    # To get the list of symbols to run the rest of the process, for now just run with one
    symbol = 'KSCL'
    self.getAnnouncements(symbol)

  def getAnnouncements(self,symbol):
    # To get a list of all announcements so far in the last few months
    # This is done by using requests and demjson because the request returns a js object
    # Open request to get everything
    payload = {'symbol' : symbol,'Industry' : '', 'ExDt' : '', 'subject' : ''}

    corporateActions_url='https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/getAnnouncements.jsp'

    r = rq.get(corporateActions_url, headers = self.req_headers, params=payload)

    for line in r.iter_lines():
      lineAscii = line.decode("ascii")
      if len(lineAscii) > 5:
        pyAnnouncements = dj.decode(lineAscii)

    #Tried setting the cookie but no use
    #cookie = r.headers['Set-Cookie']
    #self.req_headers['Cookie'] = cookie

    # read from the announcements
    if pyAnnouncements['success']:
      #for x in pyAnnouncements['rows']:
      for i in range(0,1):
        self.readAnnouncement(pyAnnouncements['rows'][i])

BuyBack_inst = BuyBack()
BuyBack_inst.start()
```

When I try this flow from browser, the second call response will have a href link to another pdf. But I am not getting that href link in my python response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me to get all PDF `href`s given a symbol and announcement period:

```
import demjson
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

symbol = 'KSCL'

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/getAnnouncements.jsp"
          f"?period=Last%201%20Month&symbol={symbol}&industry=&subject=")

for ann in demjson.decode(r.text.strip())['rows']:
    url = (
        "https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/corpInfo/equities/AnnouncementDetail.jsp?"
        f"symbol={ann['sym']}"
        f"&desc={ann['desc']}"
        f"&tstamp={int(ann['date']) // 100}"
        f"&seqId={ann['seqId']}"
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.select_one('.t1 a[href$=".pdf"]')['href'])
```

Result:

```
/corporate/KSCL_20122018134432_Outcome_046.pdf
/corporate/KSCL_20122018133033_Outcome_043.pdf
```